# jQuery scroll to bottom of page

Tags: jquery

Im using the following to scroll to the top of a page when you click a certain link.

```
$('.myLinkToTop').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

I want to make another link that scrolls to the bottom of the page. The following is working OK. I think it tries to scroll 1000px down the page, so if the page is shorter then it scrolls faster than it should, and if the page is taller then it wont go all the way to the bottom. How can I replace '1000' with the window height? Thanks

```
$('.myMenuLink').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1000}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

I know that this code jumps to the bottom of the page, but it doenst scroll smoothly like I need:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

Comment: you should be using jquery easing plugin and pass the parameter like swing , easein or easeout whatever you like for smooth transition

Comment: Just a reminder, the [currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13583503/383904) is actually incorrect / incomplete (see comment).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your requirement to animate and move to bottom of document can be achieved by the code below

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:1500px">
        <button class="myLinkToTop" id="but1" >1</button>
    </div>
        <button class="myMenuLink" id="but1" >2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$('.myLinkToTop').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
});

$('.myMenuLink').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:0
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Refer to this link

http://jsfiddle.net/q6Wsp/6/

Comment: That's an **incorrect example**. While animating to bottom the **easing** has no time to properly finish (slowdown) cause of wrong height calculations - instead it hits bottom at full speed.

Answer (score 11):

You need to substract the viewport height from the scrollHeight :

```js
$('#goToBottom').click(function(){

  var WH = $(window).height();  
  var SH = $('body').prop("scrollHeight");
  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: SH-WH}, 1000);

});
```

```css
body{height:2000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="goToBottom">GO TO BOTTOM</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
$(function () {
     $('#scrlBotm').click(function () {
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $(document).height()
         },
         1500);
         return false;
     });

     $('#scrlTop').click(function () {
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: '0px'
         },
         1500);
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

**For very long html documents** scrollTop:$(document).height() fails, 
in these cases you can use:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#endOfPage').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

at the end of page put a:

```
<div id="endOfPage">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

code jumps to the bottom of the page With smoothly:

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> $('#selector').click(function () {
>                   $('html, body').animate({
>                       scrollTop: $(document).height()
>                   }, 1000); }); });

With this code easy to scroll page down.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the bottom of page try this:

```
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('html, body').height()
        }, 'slow');
```