# Making divs from AJAX calls scroll automatically to the bottom of the parent section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I currently have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Making%20divs%20from%20AJAX%20calls%20appear%20the%20bottom%20of%20another%20section) code written out for a chat style interface and wanted to know how I could go about making it so that the container auto-scrolls to the most recent message.  As it currently stands, once the chat container have enough messages to warrant the user to scroll, the newer messages are hidden below the scroll bar.  Is there any way to have it so that the most recent message is automatically scrolled to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to bottom of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583180/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page)

Comment: post your codes here !

Answer (score 0):

if you have jquery you can use the .append() like this

```
var html='response of chat';
$('.classOfDiv').append(html);
```

And after use the scrolling function of jquery

```
$('.classOfDiv').animate({ scrollTop: $('.classOfDiv').height() }, 1000);
```

Enjoy !

Comment: where you used `after()`?

Comment: sorry i edit my post, use append() to stay in the same div