# jquery - scroll page to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I simply want to scroll a page to the bottom
seems - it is a deep secret

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    let y = $('body').height();
    console.log(y);  // 2285
    $('document').scrollTop(y);
});
```

also tried:

```
$('document').scrollTop(y + 'px');  
$('body').scrollTop(y);
$('body').scrollTop(y + 'px');
```

also tried some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583180/) - without success

please help

Comment: Have you checked [jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page) ?

Comment: try with `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:y }, 1000);`

Comment: @flyingfox - as I said - I tried

Comment: @provance It's different page,also could you post a reproduceable code to let others analysis it?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - it works, thanks. What is the logic - why animation is needed - why not just using scrollTop and the param ? Because if param is `0` - it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the alternative way. It works for me.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("button").click(function () {
      jQuery("html, body").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: jQuery("html, body").get(0).scrollHeight,
        },
        1000
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```